# rotate a star in opengl (2D)

Tags: opengl, rotation

I have a 2D star, and I don't know how to rotate it around its center, and I also don't know how to do it with a keyboard key. Also how can I make my object bigger or smaller by a certain percentage (because when I tried to do it by changing pixels, the star goes wrong).

This is my code:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

void init (void)
{
    glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,00);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    gluOrtho2D(0.0,200.0,0.0,200.0);

}
void LineSegment(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex2i(20,120);
    glVertex2i(180,120);
    glVertex2i(45,20);
    glVertex2i(100,190);
    glVertex2i(155,20);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}
int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowPosition(50,100);
    glutCreateWindow("STAR");
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(LineSegment);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For rotation, there are a couple ways to do it - rotate the vertices of the object or rotate the coordinate space that it exists in. Do you know of any OpenGL routines that aid in rotation?

Comment: No im new in OpenGL, i want to rotate it around circle with a key, and with another key make STAR bigger or smaller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you rotated the star with glRotatef() function around the z axis, it should spin around it's centre. I'd create a global variable to measure rotation, and increase decrease that value with whichever keys you want to use.
so, glRotatef(angle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); should do the trick.
Check out the NeHe tutorials, they're particularly helpful for this I found:
http://nehe.gamedev.net/

Check out the necessary ones between 1-10, there's a few on keyboard control and rotation and such.

Also, for scaling it, you could try glScalef() as well, and do the maths to increment it as a percentage which wouldn't be too hard.

Hopefully some of that is useful, I'm pretty new to all this >.>

Comment: Thanks Talen but im new in OpenGL and i dont know how to use them in my code

Comment: Haha without doing too much of your homework for you :P, 
I'd suggest having a look at these two pages:
http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glRotate.xml
http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glScale.xml

Those pages explain the functions and their parameters, an understanding of those is invaluable. Also, on the NeHe website, the lessons show you how they can be used without affecting any other models. I'd highly recommend those lessons for OpenGL, they're brilliant and very simple to follow :)